# Azure Free Websites - Pricing for free websites with SQL Server

Tags: azure

I'd like to understand how the Azure Pricing works for free websites. Can I use the `SQL` database with the free websites plan where the `SQL` database would be paid for (*I'll pay for the `SQL` database*)?

I tried using their pricing calculator, however, it mentions the `SQL` plan is a different section and I am unable to comprehend how the pricing would be calculated in my setup.

What I need to host is:

1. A very small website
2. A very small database associated with the website(*I presume I would only need a maximum of 20 tables in it*).

What I seem to understand is that the most basic SQL database plan would be sufficient for my cause. With that in mind, could someone help me understand **what would be the charges if I need a free website hosting with the most basic, minimum `SQL` database plan?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Azure SQL database with a free Azure website.  You just need to configure your website to connect to the Azure database.  In the .Net world, this is typically done using your web.config or a connection string builder.

The cheapest [Azure SQL database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) you can get is currently the Basic Tier which is priced at ~$5/mo.  The cheapest [Azure website](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/) is free as you mentioned.

If you sign up for a free website and the basic tier SQL Azure database then your monthly bill will be ~$5

Answer (score 0):

You can actually now procure a free tier database in azure. Azure will allow you 1 free database with 5 DTUs. See photo below:

[image]